# .net core 2.0 web api custom property model binding validation

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, model-validation

I'm using .net core web api to custom bind a query string property of &format=a,b,c into an enumerable list. Do this I'm using a custom IModelBinder as follows:

```
public class RequestedFormatEnumerationBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

        var value = valueProviderResult.FirstOrDefault(); // get the value as string
        if (value == null)
        {
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(new List<RequestedFormat>() { RequestedFormat.Any });
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        var options = value.Split(",");

        var potentials = Enum.GetNames(typeof(RequestedFormat));

        var formats = options
            .Where(c => potentials.Any(x => x.Equals(c, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
            .Select(c => (RequestedFormat)Enum.Parse(typeof(RequestedFormat), c, true))
            .ToList();

        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(formats);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

I'm then applying this to my model as follows:

```
    [EnumDataType(typeof(RequestedFormat))]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    [BindProperty(BinderType = typeof(RequestedFormatEnumerationBinder))]
    public IEnumerable<RequestedFormat> Formats { get; set; }
```

The model binder is called and correctly parses the input. Unfortunately the model always fails validation on the Formats property.

I've tried adding a validation attribute and adding a validation state entry to the binding context that suppresses validation but nothing seems to work.

What step am I missing?